# How to rotate URLs in an iFrame in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 arrays (that I read from an XML file):

- `urls` contains urls
- `durations` contains integers to represent seconds

I want to loop through those arrays (start from `0` again when reaching the end) in order to display, inside an iFrame:

- `urls[0].innerHTML` for `durations[0]` seconds
- `urls[1].innerHTML` for `durations[1]` seconds
- `urls[2].innerHTML` for `durations[2]` seconds

etc...

To do that I have the following code:

```
while (i <= len) {
    $j('.marquee').attr('src',urls[i].innerHTML);
    setTimeout(function(){
        i++;
        if (i >= len) {i = 0;} 
    },parseInt(duration[i].innerHTML) * 1000);
}
```

I then realized that this will run a million times through the loop before it reaches the first timeout to call the function and increase `i`.

So I wanted to just *pause* the code but I saw immediately in many stackoverflow questions that doing so is a very bad idea.

So the question is, how do I do that?

As a bonus question... where should I fadeIn() and/or fadeOut() between the URLs?

Comment: You can not use the while loop because setTimeout is asynchronous...

Comment: If don't have a lot of urls you should load them all and display only one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
var i = 0;
(function step(){
    $j('.marquee').attr('src',urls[i].innerHTML);
    i = (i+1)%len;
    setTimeout(step, parseInt(duration[i].innerHTML) * 1000);
})();
```

Notice there's no explicit loop. There's only one timeout programmed at a time.

If you want to add fadein and fadeout, you'll have to load the sources in different frames (which may be at the same position) and to fade those.

Comment: (I must leave now, I can't demonstrate the fading thing)

Comment: Great! I just moved `i = (i+1)%len` to after the `setTimeout`.

Comment: No worries for the fade in. I'll ask a new question. Thanks!